# How to set difault image in list box

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list box in my App and images are loading to the list box by using web request.so if there is a lag occur during the image loading i have to show a loading image or a default image.How can i set default images to the list box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you have a stackpanel warpping around your image area and have background for that stackpanel. So any images that haven't load will have that background and if it's failed to load it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx), to avoid lag, when loading many images in a list.